# HTML 5 Reference/Specification?

Tags: php, html, dtd, specifications

Sorry for my english.

I have PHP classes for generated HTML forms:

```
class Html_ElementInput extends Html_Element
{
    public function __construct($type=null)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->attrs = array
        (
            'type' => array('text', 'password', 'checkbox', 'radio', 'submit', 'reset', 'file', 'hidden', 'image', 'button'),
            'name' => 'CDATA',
            'value' => 'CDATA',
            'checked' => array('checked'),
            'disabled' => array('disabled'),
            'readonly' => array('readonly'),
            'size' => 'Number',
            'maxlength' => 'Number',
// ......
```

This format is analog SGML-DTD description xHTML - http://economist.rudn.ru/files/web-studio/docs/html/xhtml/xhtml_1.0/xhtml1-transitional_dtd.txt

I wanted to change their class based HTML5, but there is no description of SGML-HTML5 specification.

Do I understand correctly that the SGML-HTML5 description would not?

Comment: so your problem is related to documentation about HTML5 specifications?

Comment: yes. i want see SGML-type specification HTML5, as  http://economist.rudn.ru/files/web-studio/docs/html/xhtml/xhtml_1.0/xhtml1-transitional_dtd.txt, but specification HTML5 on w3c.org the other format, and i don't understand their.

Answer (score 1):

HTML 5 is not based on SGML. It has two serializations, XML and HTML 5. There is no SGML version of HTML 5.

As far as I know, there is no official machine readable description of the language. I expect there will be once the language stabilizes, but it is still under development.

An unofficial (likely not always up to date) [RelaxNG schema is available](https://bitbucket.org/validator/syntax/src/82eaafbf8365/relaxng/) as part of [validator.nu](http://html5.validator.nu/)

Comment: Ok. But why this specification does not have "machine readable description"? The programmers  must have a structure info about this language for their applications..  ok.. thanks!

Comment: Because it expects documents to be handled using HTML5 parsers and not general SGML parsers.